# Recursively calling a function in the exception clause

Tags: java

I would like to retry calling a function in the exception clause like this:

```
private int mTries = 0;
private void myFunction() {
    try {
      // do something 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (mTries ++ < MAX_TRIES;
             myFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

My question, regardless the stack memory usage,  calling a function recursively in the catch clause the same as calling it in normal case? I am wonder if doing this will blow off the stack, if my app is running on android platform.

```
private void anotherFunction(int i) {
      if (i == 0)
            return;
      anotherFunction(i--);
}
```

Comment: The anotherFunction(int i) looks fine, in-as-much as you don't start at i < 0. About the first usage, it's generally discouraged to use exception handlers in java for application logic, and it sucks on performance.

Comment: Agree with keni. To me this has a bad code smell to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not write it like this?

```
private void myFunction(){
   int triesRemaining = MAX_TRIES;
   while( triesRemaining-- > 0 ){
      try{
         // ... do stuff
         return;
      }
      catch( Exception e ){
      }
   }
   throw new Exception( "too many failures" );
}
```

However, I seriously recommend you narrow down the catch clause so that you only catch only those types of exception after which you'd want to continue processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your second implementation will always cause a stack overlflow.  (Try passing in a value even of 1, it will fail).

Answer (score 0):

> My question, regardless the stack memory usage, calling a function recursively in the catch clause the same as calling it in normal case?

Yes, it is exactly the same.